# jQuery script to add text to a textbox breaks when the textbox is edited

Tags: jquery

I wrote a little script to that will add blocks of text to a textbox when you click on them, and it works. But if edit something in the text box, say delete a character, the script no longer works. I have to refresh the page. Here is the code:

```js
$('#add-spec,#add-spec2,#add-spec3').click(function() {
  var currentVal = $('#current-content').html();
  var newVal = currentVal + '\n' + $(this).text();
  $('#current-content').html(newVal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id=current-content>Some current content</textarea>

<button id=add-spec>This is something to add</button>
<button id=add-spec2>My name is Eniego Montoya</button>
<button id=add-spec3>There's a snake in my boot</button>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Set the `val` of the textarea, not the html

Comment: Yes, that did it. Thanks!